# Blank page after migrating site from IIS7 to IIS8.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

We've moved a working site from Windows 2008/IIS7 to 2012/IIS8.5

When trying to load any page static or asp.net I just get a white screen. Examing the headers it's http/500.

I checked the logs and it seems to be 500.19 but no clue what the error might be.

If I modify the web.config to create a syntax error in there then the correct error page shows up.

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

But changing it back and I get the blank screen again.

Thanks

Comment: Does the new service have .Net app pools configured. Is the site configured as a webapp